# Como fazer upload de Imagens dinâmicas em JSF?

Tags: java, jsf

Qual a melhor estratégia para upload e uso de imagens em JSF?

Não quero usar campo *blob* no banco de dados, então como eu resolvo o problema da pasta de armazenamento das imagens, já que o arquivo .war é fechado.

Comment: Você saber sobre onde gravar ou como usar o JSF para fazer uploads?

Answer (score 4):

### Abordagens de upload

Existem duas abordagens para salvar arquivos de upload comumente utilizadas: salvar em DB ou em uma pasta **fora do projeto**

### Erro de início de projeto

É muito comum ver, quem está começando a trabalhar com projetos web java, o upload sendo salvo no mesmo diretório do projeto. Em outra palavras é comum pessoas salvarem os arquivos dentro da mesma pasta onde foi realizado o deploy, no caso do Tomcat, seria dentro da pasta webapps.

Por que isso é uma má prática?

Quem toma conta das pastas criadas dentro de um servidor, é ele mesmo. Ele pode muito bem apagar, rescrever, copiar ou fazer o que mais bem entender com os arquivos lá encontrados.

Nesse caso o correto seria ter uma pasta fora da área de deploy do servidor por exemplo. Algo como: "C:\uploads"

### Salvando arquivos em um banco de dados

A vantagem dessa abordagem é que ao fazer backup do banco, automaticamente está sendo feita o backup da imagem. Outra vantagem é o fato de que o código fica mais simples, para buscar uma imagem basta uma simples consulta.

As desvantagens seriam que:

1. Pesaria o banco de dados. Ao retornar uma imagem do banco isso poderia pesar a rede e o tráfego dos dados.
2. Uma consulta pelo usuário poderia retornar a foto (mesmo que não necessite) o que poderia deixar mais lento o processo (no caso de imagens pesadas).
3. Caso você queria apenas visualizar a foto você vai precisar através do sistema. Não existe a facilidade de dar 2 cliques e visualizar a foto (a não ser que o DB faça isso para você). Banco de dados mais novos tem a opção de salvar a foto em uma pasta mas como se fizesse parte de uma coluna do DB (sei que o SQLServer faz isso); o problema é que muitas empresas utilizam bancos gratuitos que não tem esse tipo de funcionalidade.

### Salvando arquivos em uma pasta

As vantagens de salvar arquivos em uma pasta seriam:

1. Facilidade para visualizar os arquivos. Bastaria um duplo clique que você poderia abrir/editar o arquivo sem atrapalhar o sistema.
2. Não pesa a rede. Nesse caso você utilizaria o sistema de IO do sistema operacional, o que deixaria a rede livre para se comunicar com o DB.
3. Facilita o modelo no banco de dados. Você não vai precisar de mapear um blob ou seja lá o que for para o banco de dados. Apenas uma String apontando o Path do arquivo.

### Então, como eu faço para exibir as fotos?

No caso do JSF você esbarrá no problema de que os componentes, nativamente, só exibem imagens que estão dentro do servidor (pelo menos os que eu conheço, pode ser que outros já tenham a função de procurar fora do servidor).

Existem soluções que você poderia fazer para exibir as imagens:

- Utilizar um servlet. Exato! Você poderia ter um servlet que leria as imagens em um determinado caminho e exibiria retornar para quem estivesse querendo ver. Tudo que teria que fazer era retornar uma URL como: uaihebert.com/imagem33.png que o servlet exibiria essa imagem. Um exemplo de servlet retornando imagem tem aqui: http://www.javatpoint.com/example-to-display-image-using-servlet
- Outra coisa que poderia ser feita, nesse caso utilizando o Primefaces, seria via código carregar os bytes da imagem em um determinado folder e depois retornar dentro de um objeto esperado pelo primefaces. (Agora o site deles está fora do ar, não consigo pegar um exemplo lá)

Comment: Muito esclarecedora sua resposta! obrigado. Lembra o nome do componente primefaces? As imagens seriam dinâmicas..

Comment: Seria o dynamic image (acho que é assim que escreve).